# How to know if we can use half4 instead of float4?

Tags: ios, shader, metal, metalkit

in metal shader implementation, it is recommended to use half4 instead of float4. but how to know if we can use half4 instead of float4? how to know the amount of precision we need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know you can use `half4`, instead of `float4`, depending on how the colour is encoded as it's passed into the fragment shader.

Half-precision floats can represent the values 0 to 2048 exactly so if it's used to represent an 8-bit channel (i.e. pretty much all commonly-used texture formats) then there is no loss of fidelity.

It will also save memory transfer bandwidth, which is important on mobile platforms.

Comment: How are you deriving 2048?

Comment: @nullspace looking at this again I might have that wrong with the precision only being 10 bits (0-1023). However the point is that this still covers the 8 bits required.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

**float:**

> A 32-bit floating-point. The float data type must conform to the IEEE
>   754 single precision storage format.

Full **float** precision is generally used for world space positions, texture coordinates, or scalar computations involving complex functions such as trigonometry or power/exponentiation.

**half:**

> A 16-bit floating-point. The half data type must conform to the IEEE
>   754 binary16 storage format.

**Half** precision is useful for short vectors, directions, object space positions, high dynamic range colors.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to know when `half4` can be used instead of `float4`, not what they are.

Answer (score 0):

From : [enter link description here](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/SL-DataTypesAndPrecision.html)
A general rule of thumb is to start with half precision for everything except positions and texture coordinates. Only increase precision if half precision is not enough for some parts of the computation.